# Would Goku have won from the start against Freeza?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

In the Freeza Saga, Gohan, Krillin, Piccolo, and Vegeta all battle Freeza from his first form to his final.  At each stage, someone is able to over power him, if even slightly and cause him damage, thus sapping portions of his energy reserve.  Likewise, Freeza's transformations require energy for him to transform to the next level, thus using more energy.

Lets assume that Freeza never made the unnecessary transformations, never fought the others, Goku could already transform into a Super Saiyan, and both fighters had their exact same power levels and fighting abilities.

Freeza had been fighting the others for at least half an hour longer before Goku even showed up and Goku was at full strength when their battle first began.  Freeza was also using less than a quarter of his own power while fighting Goku in his base form, 50% while Goku was a Super Saiyan, and 100% by the end, at which point he was actually equal, if not stronger than Goku.  If I remember correctly, the only reason 100% Freeza didn't dominate Goku is because he was tired from the extended fighting he had done.

So, if these two warriors had met from the start and done so at full power, with Goku having the ability to transform, and Freeza not making any useless transformations, **would Goku have won their battle?**

**FYI:** It's not opinion based because I'm asking about both characters at a specific time when all information required to determine and answer is provided canonically.  This isn't like a "Who's faster Superman or Flash?" question.  Both characters strengths and weaknesses are clearly defined and at no point vary.  If you don't know, don't mark for closure, that's not grounds to close a question.

Comment: You misremember things. Frieza was no match for Goku once he hit Super Saiyan -- at any level. Goku toyed with him, hoping to turn him rather than having to kill him, and Frieza only gave up by way of cutting himself in half.

Comment: @Axelrod but once he powered up to 100%, he actually did get the upper hand on Goku, even knocked him out at one point.

Comment: at 100% freeza landed a few punches, and lost anyway. im pretty sure goku even says, he was holding back to see what 100% frieza could do, and then he droped a can of hurt all over frieza's stupid face

Comment: So... does that mean the answer is, "Yes"?

Comment: @Ellesedil It does.

Comment: How many times has Freeza been to the point of losing, then held his arms up and called upon the power of the earth, then totally destroyed his enemy in one hit when the earth sent him its power? Goku has more than once. I don't think Freeza ever had a chance.

Comment: FYI: I don't think you understand the complexities behind our "primarily opinion based" close reason. If you have to "determine the answer" by any means other than seeing it on the screen, it's opinion based.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield: Considering the answer, which seems quite authoritative, is this really opinion based?

Comment: IMO, yes, since you are still just speculating that nothing else could possibly have happened to make the weaker person win anyway. That happens all the time in fiction.

Comment: Freeza only starts losing power after he goes into his final form and pushes the line. That stressed bulky mode he's in. Goku intentionally pushes him to this point to make him more controllable and more willing to give up and resolve the situation without killing him. So SSJ Goku is at max power and draining for a longer period than Freeza is and the fight previous to that point is Goku's body being wrecked by both the power difference and the use of high level Kaio-ken repeatedly which shreds the users body, where as Freeza was pretty much unharmed overall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Goku would have won the battle with Frieza if both had started at the power level they ended the fight at.

Goku's full power level, when he first went Super Saiyan, was 150,000,000.  Frieza's at 100%, on the other hand, was only 120,000,000. 
[These figures](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_power_levels#Dragon_Ball_Z) are taken from Daizenshuu 7, from a series of guides written by one of the co-authors of the manga and include input from Toriyama himself.

Goku also points out their power difference, later in the fight, after Frieza expends most of his power attempting to kill Goku (to no avail).